# Regular expression excluding sequences of same(predefined) char

Tags: regex

I need to write regular expression that will match any sequence of predefined chars, ie in string "Hello,, world, xaxxa" will find double comma and x, but not the single occurencies. Hope this is not duplicate question but I could not find any answer... Thanks for help

Comment: Does it have to be consecutive occurrences of these characters?

Comment: are you also trying to find the double "l" in "Hello"?

Comment: I have a defined set of characters which sequences I need to find...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
(.)\1+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30lhn)

`(.)` matches any character and store it in a backreference (because of the brackets around). With the `\1` you access this backreference.

So this will match any sequence of the same character.

If you have a defined set of characters, use a character class

```
([,x])\1+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30lht)

you can add any character to the class inside the square brackets.

Comment: yes this is what I need, only that I have predefined set of chars which sequences I need to find... in this case I dont want to find those "ll"